# Copy files from Network Mapped Drive

Tags: batch

I am trying to copy a file over from a mapped drive on a network to the current computer through a batch file.

I've already attempted the following below and still no results. The plan is to run a batch file to copy a file from a network drive down to the local C:\ drive.

```
@echo off
copy H:\Videos\TargetVideo\TargetVideo.mp4 C:\Video\
```

Comment: You can use `xcopy /y /f "H:\Videos\TargetVideo\TargetVideo.mp4" "C:\Video\"` just like that. Otherwise use the unc path to the share of the "H" drive rather than the drive so `xcopy /y /f "\\server\share\Videos\TargetVideo\TargetVideo.mp4" "C:\Video\"` And turn `@ECHO ON` and see what it prints out error wise, etc.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the syntax of your command. What error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any errors at all but I will try the `@ECHO ON` and see what it prints out. My syntax might be correct but when I run the batch no file is moved to my target directory.

Comment: Aren't you suppose to use the command like: `copy H:\Videos\TargetVideo\TargetVideo.mp4 C:\Video\TargetVideo.mp4`?

Comment: Does the `C:\Video` folder exist? Do you have permissions to it? Also, drop the backslash after `C:\Video`.

Comment: @Cown it's not necessary to specify the name of the destination file. If you omit a destination filename, COPY simply keeps the original filename.

Comment: @Twisty Roger that.

Comment: I will attempt these responses in a few hours and I will update accordingly.

Comment: Attempted @McDonald's solution and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: @McDonald's, thank you so much again! I did my research but did not get a straight answer or any examples that were working for some odd reason so that is why I came here.

Comment: No worries, you came to the right place and did the right thing so it's all good; I'm glad to be able to help you get your problem resolved.

Comment: @BSwordsman please could you let me know which response worked because McDonald isnt a user in the comments above, presumably they have changed their username since commenting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [XCOPY](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) with the `/Y` switch to suppress prompting and confirm overwriting the destination file with the source file if it already exist, and you can use the `/F` switch to display the full source and destination file and path during the copy operation.

Additionally, be sure to put double quotes around the full source file and the destination path. Also, be sure to turn `@ECHO ON` in the script to see this output detail from the command window.

### Example Script Drive Letter

```
xcopy /y /f "H:\Videos\TargetVideo\TargetVideo.mp4" "C:\Video\"
```

---

You could use the UNC path rather than the drive letter which the actual drive letter points to:

### Example Script UNC Path

```
xcopy /y /f "\\<server>\<share>\Videos\TargetVideo\TargetVideo.mp4" "C:\Video\"
```

---

### Further Resources

- [XCOPY](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)
- [ECHO](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)