# How to copy files over the LAN with a cmd batch file?

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file

How to copy files over the LAN with a cmd batch file?

I want when i execute the .bat to send my file from PCUSER1/Desktop to PCUSER2/DESKTOP?

How do I do that?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1228643/copy-files-from-network-mapped-drive

Comment: To elaborate on @somebadhat's comment, if copying a single file at a time `xcopy` is the most efficient.  If looking to copy multiple files at a time, [`RoboCopy`](https://superuser.com/a/1537177/529800) would be most efficient

Answer (score 0):

You have some options (assuming you have full control / access on the other PC).

1. Remote Desktop to the other PC, and copy your files into the remote desktop session, and run it
2. psexec (part of [pstools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools)) can also do this remotely (again some setup is required at the other end, and it is all possible if you have full control / access on the other PC).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Team Viewer or Ammy Admin to transfer and execute the application in the other pcs running via LAN

Hope it helps.